# Can't read from or write to SQLite database in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is the onCreate in my database class. I extended it with SQLiteOpenHelper. I create three tables and I can see them in my db browser.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;

    final String SQL_CREATE_TODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TODOTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            TODOTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TODOTable.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
            TODOTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
            TODOTable.COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            TODOTable.COLUMN_PRIORITY + " TEXT, " +
            TODOTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TODO_TABLE);

    final String SQL_CREATE_PRIORITY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            PriorityTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            PriorityTable.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PRIORITY_TABLE);

    final String SQL_CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            CategoryTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            CategoryTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            CategoryTable.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
}
```

This is the method I try to add priorites with:

```
public void addPriority(String priority) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PriorityTable.COLUMN_NAME, priority);
    db.insert(PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

This is the method I try to read the priorities from my database:

```
public List<String> getAllPriorities() {
    List<String> priorityList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            priorityList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return priorityList;
}
```

This is the onCreate in my Priorities activity. It's always empty even if I add data to my database via the database browser.

```
List<String> priorityList = new ArrayList<>();
TODODbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_priorities);

    dbHelper = new TODODbHelper(this);
    priorityList = dbHelper.getAllPriorities();
}
```

When I want to add data to my database in this activity it looks like this:

```
dbHelper.addPriority(newPriority.getText().toString());
```

After calling the addPriority nothing happens. I don't see anything changing in my database and the next time I open the app, it crashes and I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
```

While debugging I found a CursorIndex out of bounds exception and that no matter what I do my cursor is always at -1, which should be fixed by moveToFirst.

Also if I add data to my database via browser after trying to add data with my addPriorities method the _ID is incremented.

My first thought was that I mixed up my constants, but if that's the case I really can't see it.

Comment: You are trying to get a non existing column.

Comment: `getColumnIndex` [returns the index for a particular *column* name](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)). You're passing it a table name.

Comment: Thank you Kling Klang and Matt Gibson. I knew I mixed up my constants. I also found out that adding data via browser doesn't do anything. It's just a browser after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your/an issue is with the following line:-

```
priorityList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME)));
```

PriorityTable.TABLE_NAME is not a name of a column in the Cursor, hence the offset of -1 returned from the `getColumnIndex` method.

The line should probably be :-

```
priorityList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PriorityTable.COLUMN_NAME)));
```

> Also if I add data to my database via browser after trying to add data
>   with my addPriorities method the _ID is incremented.

You can use your browser tool to modify the database. However you need to save the database and then copy the file to the device in the appropriate location.